# Injection safe parameterized queries with sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been reading documentation for sqlite and found that many sources strongly recommend avoiding python string substitution in queries since it makes them vulnerable to injection attacks:

Avoid:

```python
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % table_name)

conn.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name))
```

I've seen several simple examples where string formatting like this is replaced with slqlite parameters:

```python
values = ('my_table', '1')
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ROWID = ?", values)
```

---

This works in the simple case, but fails when I want to retrieve the parameter values from a list as in this example:

Working code with string formatting:

```python
c.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
for i in range(len(amt_l)):
    c.execute("""
              INSERT INTO transactions ({}, {}, {}, {}, {})
              VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')
              """.format(header[0], header[1], header[2], header[3], header[4],
                         date_l[i], party_l[i], direction_l[i], ctr_party_l[i], amt_l[i]))
db.commit()
```

Non-working code using parameters:

```python
c.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
for i in range(len(amt_l)):
    values = (header[0], header[1], header[2], header[3], header[4],
              date_l[i], party_l[i], direction_l[i], ctr_party_l[i], amt_l[i])
    c.execute("""
              INSERT INTO transactions (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
              """, values)
```

Is there a way to use `?` to fill in parameters in the sql query when the parameter values are retrieved from a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610056/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-column-names-via-bind-variables-in-oracle asks the underlying question for Oracle, but the answer is true to all sane SQL databases. (Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723931/passing-table-and-column-name-dynamically-using-bind-variables)

Comment: ...also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements asks that same question (and gets the same answer) for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bind variables to parameterize *values*. You can't parameterize *column names* (or table names, or the names of other SQL objects).

Using untrusted data for these names would be *innately* insecure -- and moreover, making this possible would prevent up-front analysis (of which indexes can be used or otherwise how to efficiently execute a query), which is a non-security-related benefit of prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I've been writing SQL for about a year now, but I'm relatively new to interacting with a database in python. Am I understanding correctly that the issue isn't that I'm filling in the parameter from a value in a list, but rather that I'm using a parameter for something I'm not allowed to?

Comment: @Evan, exactly right.