# Python Sqlite3 OperationalError when running UPDATE

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm running the following Python3 code on a Sqlite3 database:

`db.execute("UPDATE user SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?", (name, quantity, str(g.user['id'])))`

where `db` is my cursor object. However, this produces the error

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`.

Is this the right syntax for `cursor.execute()`?

Answer (score 0):

f-strings would do the job in python3

```py
db.execute(f"UPDATE user SET {name} = {quantity} WHERE id = {str(g.user['id']}"
```

Comment: and don't forget to commit your changes

Comment: I know that using a `?` provides security against an injection. Would f-strings provide the same level of security, or do I need to sanitize the input on my own?

Comment: The problem here is that you parametrize a column `{name}` that is not allowed to be filled in using parameters `?`. If you need secure parameters, you would need to specify a column than. There is a question about security https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752966/2630643

Comment: Got it. Thanks!
My code ended up being 

`db.execute("UPDATE user SET " + name + " = ? WHERE id = ?", (quantity, str(g.user['id'])))` 
since the column name isn't specified by the user, I just had it as a variable in order to loop.